# Abstract Class Hold Member Field or Use Getter() of Concrete Implementation?

Tags: java, oop, variables, abstract, member

One OOP principle I'm struggling with is Abstract Classes and their ability to hold member fields (variables).

Take for instance the following code (**example 1**):

```
public abstract class AbstractClassConstructor {

    List mList;

    public AbstractClassConstructor(List list) {
        mList = list;
    }

    public Object getListRow(int row) {
        return mList.get(row);
    }
}
```

And please inspect this alternative code which provides the same functionality (**example 2**):

```
public abstract class AbstractClassGetter {

    public abstract List getList();

    public Object getListRow(int row) {
        return getList().get(row);
    }
}
```

I'm concerned with whether **example 1** or **example 2** is more maintainable, as well, I would like to follow OOP standards as close as possible.

Currently I see more coupling in example 1 than I do example 2, though I don't see many other issues. Example 2 however is more straight-forward, I like that the concrete implementation holds the private field and the `AbstractClassGetter` uses a method to fetch it. This feels better, but I'm struggling to apply the correct OOP principle to help me know which IS better from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, **example 1** would not be ideal if `mList` will be used in the child class with `mList`'s function that is specific to its type (e.g. LinkedList or ArrayList). This is because it might need to be cast to its actual type before it could get used. In this case **example 2** would be better.

If there's no function of specific type needed in the child class, then **example 1** would be better in term of encapsulation.

**Updated**

Another approach, where perhaps could be considered the middle ground is to use Generic.

```
public abstract class AbstractClassConstructor<T extends List> {

    T mList;

    public AbstractClassConstructor(T list) {
        mList = list;
    }

    public Object getListRow(int row) {
        return mList.get(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact you are correct that mList is utilized in the child class, and yes it's more specific type ArrayList is necessary for the child class. This is in fact why I ended up with example 2. So I suppose I chose the correct route for this task. I now understand how both would be useful, thank you.

Comment: Sounds good. I have also added another option for your consideration. If the answer is good for you, perhaps you could tick the answer and upvote it :). I like your question, have star it and upvote it. It triggers me to think of the reason which I didn't thought of previously.